Как исправить усечение модели при приближении?
Делаю AR приложение, которое должно отображать 3D модели при наведении на картинку. При приближении получаю обрезку модели как при большом значении ClippingPlanes.Near, хотя оно установлено в 0.01. Я так же пробовал добавить вторую камеру, дочерней к XR камере. Пробовал уменьшать и увеличить MeshBounds у моделей.
Видимо я что-то делаю не так.


Оказалось что проблема была в слишком низком PhysicsSize указанным для картинок в ReferenceImageLibrary. Я ожидал, что это значение просто скейлит 3D объект в соответсвии с размером картинки на камере. А оказалось, что на скейл этот показатель не влияет. За то вляет на ClippingPlane. Поставил в PhysicsSize значение 0.1 вместо 0.01 и ве начало нормально работать
